# Not able to install levmar (Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear least squares algorithms in C/C++) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

I was trying to install levmar from the link [Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear least squares algorithms in C/C++](http://users.ics.forth.gr/%7Elourakis/levmar/). Firstly, install suitesparse and metis.

```
sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev
sudo apt-get install libmetis-dev
```

Then done the following two steps:

```
1.Download Levmar and extract it.
2.Open Terminal in that directory and input “make”;
```

After make in the terminal I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf2c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'lmdemo' failed
make: *** [lmdemo] Error 1
```

Im running on Ubuntu 16.04. Any help how to fix the error?
Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt install f2c` / `sudo apt install libf2c2`?

Comment: after sudo apt install f2c I got another error: The error is now: `/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/lmdemo.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'lmdemo' failed
make[2]: *** [lmdemo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Any help on the second error?

Comment: See this question: [undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527665/undefined-reference-to-symbol-expglibc-2-2-5)

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes back jumped into the same issue, but I alternatively install it using pip3. I hope it also helps

`pip3 install --user --upgrade pytest levmar`

[image]

you might want to read more from https://pypi.org/project/levmar/